# Cordova XHR requests failing by prefixing url with file:///

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ajax, cordova

My app is working just fine after `cordova run browser`, but it cannot connect to my backend server when deployed to iOS using `cordova run ios` (local resources load properly).

Debugger tells me the problem may be that it prefixes all XHR requests to backend server with `file:///var`, so that instead of `http://my-backend.com/rest` It tries to connect to `file:///varhttp://my-backend.com/rest`.

I have whitelist plugin installed, `<access origin="*" />` in my config and this line in index.html when deploying to iOS:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; content-src *">
```

If it's important, on front end I use Angular with ngCordova and Restangular plugin for handling AJAX requests. I use Cordova 6.2.0.

So the question is, how do I get rid of this `file:///var` prefix?

**EDIT:**
As it turns out, there's a similar error on Android device, but the prefix is `file:///android_asset`

**EDIT 2:**
My AJAX calls are made with Restangular. I have default url set like this:
`RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("http://my-backend.com")`, and example call looks like this: `Restangular.one('session/check').get()`

Comment: Can you post your code for an example Ajax request having this issue please?

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @MichaelBurger I think I did, but to be honest, it was a long time ago and I don't remember the solution. I believe it involved forking Restangular repo and hardcoding some changes. I don't have access to this project now, so I cannot make sure.